# Compare program file input.txt with file output.txt

Tags: java, bash, file, diff, readline

I have a file input.txt passed to a data structure in Java from command line. My job is to keep the structure sorted and return the boolean for insert, find, and delete calls.
input.txt is a file of 50,000 calls and output.txt is a file of 50,000 expected booleans. Each test is a new line. I want to use a command to tell me how many cases I fail (if any) and which ones I fail. How can I accomplish this?

edit:

So I'm getting asked to include code. There isn't really code. My program works, it outputs 50,000 booleans, from the input.txt  file it takes as an argument.

What I want to do is fast compare my  outputs with the given outputs in output.txt
So something like

```
diff javaFile output.txt
```

Update: for anyone that stumbles on this question, my prof showed me a way to get the printed outputs into a file in a bash command using redirection.
the formatting is as follows:

```
java file.java args >fileouts.txt
```

after which you can call diff on the files.

Comment: How can anyone answer this question without seeing any code/sample data?

Comment: Your operating system is...?

Comment: Why do you need sample data @anubhavia? My program works but I want to compare it to a 50,000 item file. Did you want me to share a 50,000 item file of booleans?

My OS is Mac OSX @laune. I learned about diff in bash but I did not learn how to implement it on a java output as 1 of my arguments

Comment: Whats is the code you have tried?

Comment: If you write your 50,000 boolean results to a file "myout.txt" we can easily determine the number of failures.

Comment: so how do I write my outputs to a file @laune? I like the idea, but I'm still learning bash haha

Comment: A simple way is to System.out.println and redirect standard output `java ... >myout.txt`

Comment: or `java ... | paste --delimiters=, - desired_output | grep ...` per my answer below (just replace `your_output` with `-` and prefix the `java ... |` command with a pipe)

Comment: **Did you want me to share a 50,000 item file of booleans?** Do you really understand the meaning of **sample data**?

Comment: Yes @anubhava. My sample data is non-trivial.

Comment: @user3466773 Most useful data is non-trivial; that's not an excuse. If it's binary you can pass it to `hexdump` or something similar to get readable output.

Comment: I saw no reason to include any code or sample output in this case, @l0b0. I asked for a command in bash or a means in java to test for different boolean results between my outputs and a given output.txt file. This is implemented across 3 different codes, and my algorithms are irrelevant as I already have them printing the correct outputs to the trivial test cases. I wanted to know how to compare the non-trivial outputs of 50,000 items.

No further code is necessary for my inquiry.

Comment: @user3466773 thanks for accepting. while `diff` might work for you, the problem in general is that if your program outputs `TFTFFTFFFTFFFF` and the correct output is `FTFFTFFFTFFFFT` then `diff` will only show 2 lines of differences whereas your program got 8 test cases wrong! btw, +1 for the precise question -- just the title was enough to understand what you needed.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed with using `diff myout output | wc -l` returned 8 when I only failed 2 cases. I'm not sure why, but I am still learning bash so hopefully I will at some point haha
@necromancer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix: `paste --delimiters=, your_output desired_output | grep -iv 'true,true' | grep -iv 'false,false' | wc -l` will give you the count of how many tests failed.

**Explanation:** If the files `your_output` and `desired_output` contain `true` or `false` on each line, then `paste` will output lines such as `true,true`, `true,false`, etc. with first value from `your_output` and second value from `desired_output`.  Next, the two `grep`s will eliminate lines (because `-v`) that correspond to the passing test cases which have the same first and second values. Finally, `wc -l` will count the lines, which correspond to the failed test cases.

**Update:** You can generalize this by using this pipeline instead: `paste --delimiters=, your_output desired_output | grep -Ev '^(.*),\1$' | wc -l`

It cuts down multiple `grep`s to one that looks for matches between any output not just `true` or `false`. The `-E` is necessary to use the `\1` which refers to the first part of the regular expression in parentheses: `(.*)`. The `^` and `$` force the entire line from beginning `^` to end `$` to be matched when looking for two identical strings separated by a `,`.

Comment: Fixed the quote and added -i. (Java prints true and false, but who knows)

Comment: If you combine this with `java ... | paste --delimiters=, - desired_output |...` you'll have it all in one fell swoop, provided the Java program writes true and false (and nothing else - but even this might be cooked) to standard output.

Comment: @laune exactly my comment on OP after yours :)

Comment: Well, we know our *nix ;-)

Comment: @laune yes we do: `java ... | paste --delimiters=, - desired_output | grep -Ev '^(.*),\1$' | wc -l` ;-)

Comment: `paste --delimiter=, a.txt b.txt | awk '/se,t|ue,f/{n++;} END{print n;}'` ;-) Down to 2 programs.